# Numpy memory management

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to apply the numpy palette method following this tutorial: http://opencvpython.blogspot.it/2012/06/fast-array-manipulation-in-numpy.html

But I got a wrong image using the following code:

```
palette_array = numpy.array(self.palette.tolist())
rgba_matrix = palette_array[self.matrix_values]
image = Image.fromarray(rgba_matrix, mode='RGBA')
...
```

Using the following one, everything works as excepted:

```
palette_array = numpy.array(self.palette.tolist())
rgba_matrix = palette_array[self.matrix_values]
img = numpy.empty((640, 480), numpy.uint32)
for col in xrange(640):
    for row in xrange(480):
        img[row, col] = rgba_matrix[row, col]
image = Image.fromarray(img, mode='RGBA')
...
```

I think it's a problem related to memory management and linked objects.

What can I do to avoid for-loops?

Thanks!

Comment: In what way is the image wrong? Wrong dimensions? Transposed? Wrong palette? etc

Comment: @NPE it's a mix of transposed-interlaced and wrong palette value. You can take a look at these results [wrong](http://imgur.com/HUMTrAI) and [good](http://imgur.com/el4UYXu)

Comment: It would be helpful if you included your full source code, or a link to it.

Comment: @farenorth it's part of a complex project so I extracted the code we need and you can test it: http://pastebin.com/M4nQYy51 
Thanks

Comment: The difference between the good and bad images has to do with your `normalize_matrix` method being applied to your `matrix` twice. If you copy the matrix and input the copy to the second image creation call, then the images are the same.  Here you go: http://pastebin.com/6xwuBpph

Comment: @farenorth: the result is still wrong :(. 
I got [good](http://imgur.com/iOytFha) and [bad](http://imgur.com/fR1mqVq)

Comment: Yes, I forgot something. Your problem was two fold: 1) the one I listed above, and 2) the array you input to Image.fromarray is a `uint32` in 'good', and a `int64` in 'bad'. I updated my paste (line 9) to make self.palette a `uint32`, and this code now produces identical images.

Comment: @farenorth: thank you so much. 
I learned a big rule: check datatype :) 
Thanks again.